# Is there any way to pass value from from servlet to calling business methods without sending it as parameter

Tags: java, servlets

I have a Servlet which calls some business methods and have a requirement to generate a unique transaction id for each and every request this servlet process and we need to pass this transaction id to the business methods.

One solution would be passing this transaction id as a parameter to all the business methods. But this is not a good solution as the code is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: assign the id to a property , and access it everywhere

Comment: I am finding approaches where it is not required to pass as a parameter, suppose servlet calling the business method without a parameter.  How to get transactionid or other property (like loguserName and role) in such method

Comment: define the property in a property file . Now this is accessible by all Servlets/classes inside the war  using getProperty() .  Sounds good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by use of ThreadLocal.

Thread Local can be considered as a scope of access, like a request scope or session scope. It’s a thread scope. You can set any object in Thread Local and this object will be global and local to the specific thread which is accessing this object. I have referred [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/java-thread-local-%E2%80%93-how-use)  to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add it as a thread local variable in the servlet and access it for anywhere else. Each incoming request would spawn a new thread and thread local variable  would be local to that thread alone

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have used thread local to store user-specific value.